# Uploading a file (image) doesn't work on live server but works on dev

Tags: php, ajax, symfony, file-upload, symfony4

Can't wrap my head around this. The following code works on my local computer but after uploading the site to the server I don't seem to receive the file in the request.

This is my ajax:

```
dialogUploadPhoto.find('form').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: $(this).attr('method'),
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        data: $(this).serializeForm(), // method below...
        // data: formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        success: function(response) {
            // The response has the correct date on my local server
            dialogUploadPhoto.dialog( "close" );
        },
        error: function (xhr, desc, err){
            // On the live server, the debugger hits
        }
    });
});
```

The serializeForm method is just a jquery method to append all fields into a `FormData` instance:

```
$.fn.serializeForm = function() {
    var form = $(this),
        formData = new FormData();
    var formParams = form.serializeArray();

    $.each(form.find('input[type="file"]'), function(i, tag) {
        $.each($(tag)[0].files, function(i, file) {
            formData.append(tag.name, file);
        });
    });

    $.each(formParams, function(i, val) {
        formData.append(val.name, val.value);
    });

    return formData;
};
```

The symfony controller method that handles the form looks like this:

```
/**
 * Matches /admin/upload/foto
 * @Route(
 *     "/upload/foto",
 *     options={"expose": true},
 *     name="admin_upload_foto")
 * @Method({"POST"})
 * @return JsonResponse
 */
public function upload_photo(
    Request $request
) {
    $response = new JsonResponse();

    $newPhoto = new Fotos();
    $photoForm = $this->createForm(PhotoType::class, $newPhoto);
    $photoForm->handleRequest($request);

    if ($photoForm->isSubmitted() && $photoForm->isValid()) {
        // This part is hit on the dev server
    } else if ($photoForm->isSubmitted()) {
        // This part is hit on the live server!
        // categorie contains no errors
        $photoForm['categorie']->getErrors()->__toString());
        // file contains an error: content-type is null;
        $photoForm['file']->getErrors()->__toString());
        $response->setStatusCode(400);
        $response->setData(array("result" => 0, "errors" => $errors));
    } else {
        $response->setStatusCode(400);
        $response->setData(array("result" => 0, "errors" => "Het foto-formulier is niet verzonden naar de server"));
    }
    return $response;
}
```

The specific error states that the file uploaded file's mime type is null.
Does that mean the file is never sent?
If I do this: `formData.getAll('file')` I can see that the file is actually in the bag.

In Chrome's network profiler I can see that the payload does include the file, maybe it is lost along the way?

**As requested**
Here is the var_dump of $_FILES on the live server

```
array(1) {
  ["photo"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["file"]=>
      string(8) "test.png"
    }
    ["type"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["file"]=>
      string(9) "image/png"
    }
    ["tmp_name"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["file"]=>
      string(14) "/tmp/phpwy5m9y"
    }
    ["error"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["file"]=>
      int(0)
    }
    ["size"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["file"]=>
      int(25745)
    }
  }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Can you do a `var_dump($_FILES)`?

Comment: You know you can replace `$(this).serializeForm()` with `new FormData(this)`

Comment: Musa, don't think so, FormData doesn't send the file for me. Neither live or dev servers receive the file that way

Comment: @MehdiBounya I just added the var_dump

Comment: @Musa Besides, FormData is initialized in the `serializeForm` function. That's the only way the file is picked up correctly (and sent to the server) on my local dev server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution but I had to ditch automatic mime type checking for it.

As per [symfony documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/upload_file.html) I shouldn't care about the file being stored as a string. The mime type checking should be 'guessed' correctly by symfony but the Assert rule for mime types doesn't pick up the mime type of the uploaded file.

I removed the mimetype assert rule and changed my handling method as follows using manual extension checking:

```
    $newPhoto = new Fotos();
    $photoForm = $this->createForm(PhotoType::class, $newPhoto);
    $photoForm->handleRequest($request);
    //        var_dump($photoForm->getData());
    if ($photoForm->isSubmitted() && $photoForm->isValid()) {
        // $file stores the uploaded PDF file
        /* @var $file UploadedFile */
        $file = $newPhoto->getFile();
        $fileExtension = $file->guessClientExtension();
    //            var_dump($file->guessClientExtension());
        if (($fileExtension === 'png' || $fileExtension === 'jpeg' || $fileExtension === 'jpg')) {
           // Now I know the extension matches the type of files I want to handle
        } else {
           // Now I know the uploaded file is an invalid type
        }
    }
```